# I cannot understand deps of react hooks?

Tags: reactjs

I understand hooks of react but when I see some example code I cannot understand. for example:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(...)

useEffect(()=>{ .... }, [setCount] )
// or
useCallback( func, [setCount] )
```

I didnt understand when use `setCount` in deps? Please explain me how it works and please understand with examples. Thanks

Comment: On this example, the useEffect will be triggered when the setCount is modified, changed or updated

Comment: You want to invoke code when `setCount` or `count` changes?  I'm wondering if it's a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good question, actually `setCount` here is a bit confusing to someone new to Javascript or React.

The usage here isn't trying to invoke it, it basically tries to tell you if `setCount` changes, the `useEffect` will be invoked.

However `setCount`, by design, never changes after the creation, thus you can simply do the following without any difference.

```
  useEffect() => { setCount(...) }, [])
```

You will get the same behavior, but the compiler will sometimes give you a warning saying you are missing a dependency, because `setCount` is used inside.

NOTE: `setCount` is a function, or a reference, only `setCount()` invokes it.